# How to remove additional spacing between the quotes in a list of values?

Tags: dictionary, filter, ansible, whitespace, trim

How do I remove the additional spacing from the left and right side of each value between the quotation marks?

This is a shorter version of a much longer list. Some values have additional spacing in the front and back, such as *Code*, *Date of Submission*, and *First Name*, while others are normal (no additional spacing).

```yaml
    "userdata": [
        {
            "AliasName": "Alias Name",
            "Code": " Code "
            "DateofSubmission": " Date of Submission ",
            "Description": "Description",
            "FirstName": " First Name ",
            "path": "path"
        },
        {
            "AliasName": "",
            "Code": " #3091 ",
            "DateofSubmission": " 14/5/2023 ",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": " Peter ",
            "path": "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local" 
        },
        {
            "AliasName": "",
            "Code": " #3092 ",
            "DateofSubmission": " 2/5/2023 ",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": " Sam ",
            "path": "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
        },
        {
            "AliasName": "",
            "Code": " #3093 ",
            "DateofSubmission": " 10/5/2023 ",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": " Judy ",
            "path": "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local" 
        }
    ]
```

I have tried these two ways with the trim filter, but nothing changed.

```yaml
    - name: Extract the list with fields
      set_fact:
        userdata: "{{ userdata | map('trim') | list }}"
```

```yaml
    - name: Extract the list with fields
      set_fact:
        userdata: "{{ userdata | trim }}"
```

---

Minimal play:

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    userdata:
      - {k1a: v1a, k1b: v1b, k1c: v1c}
      - {k2a: v2a, k2b: v2b}
      - {k3a: v3a}

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        userdata: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for i in userdata %}
          {% set keys=i.keys()|map('trim') %}
          {% set values=i.values()|map('trim') %}
          - {{ dict(keys|zip(values)) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}

    - debug:
        var: userdata|to_yaml
```

Results of minimal play:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% filter from_yaml %}\n{% for i in userdata %}\n{% set keys=i.keys()|map('trim') %}\n{% set values=i.values()|map('trim') %}\n- {{ dict(keys|zip(values)) }}\n{% endfor %}\n{% endfilter %}\n): sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found"}
```

Play to isolate the problem:

```
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    ud:
      - {k1a: v1a, k1b: v1b, k1c: v1c}
      - {k2a: v2a, k2b: v2b}
      - {k3a: v3a}

    ud_keys: "{{ ud|json_query('[].keys(@)') }}"
    ud_vals: "{{ ud|json_query('[].values(@)') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ud_keys|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: ud_vals|to_yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}
          {{ k }} {{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}
          {{ dict(k|zip(v)) }}
          {% endfor %}

    - name: Test 1
      set_fact:
        ud: |
          [{% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}
          {{ dict(k|zip(v)) }},
          {% endfor %}]
    - debug:
        var: ud
    - debug:
        var: ud|type_debug


    - name: Test 2
      set_fact:
        ud: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          [{% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}
          {{ dict(k|zip(v)) }},
          {% endfor %}]
          {% endfilter %}
      ignore_errors: true
    - debug:
        var: ud
    - debug:
        var: ud|type_debug


    - name: Test 3
      set_fact:
        ud: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}
          - {{ dict(k|zip(v)) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}
      ignore_errors: true
    - debug:
        var: ud
    - debug:
        var: ud|type_debug
```

Results of the play to isolate the problem:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ud_keys|to_yaml": "- [k1a, k1b, k1c]\n- [k2a, k2b]\n- [k3a]\n"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ud_vals|to_yaml": "- [v1a, v1b, v1c]\n- [v2a, v2b]\n- [v3a]\n"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "['k1a', 'k1b', 'k1c'] ['v1a', 'v1b', 'v1c']\n['k2a', 'k2b'] ['v2a', 'v2b']\n['k3a'] ['v3a']\n"
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "{'k1a': 'v1a', 'k1b': 'v1b', 'k1c': 'v1c'}\n{'k2a': 'v2a', 'k2b': 'v2b'}\n{'k3a': 'v3a'}\n"
}

TASK [Test 1] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"ud": [{"k1a": "v1a", "k1b": "v1b", "k1c": "v1c"}, {"k2a": "v2a", "k2b": "v2b"}, {"k3a": "v3a"}]}, "changed": false}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ud": [
        {
            "k1a": "v1a",
            "k1b": "v1b",
            "k1c": "v1c"
        },
        {
            "k2a": "v2a",
            "k2b": "v2b"
        },
        {
            "k3a": "v3a"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ud|type_debug": "list"
}

TASK [Test 2] ******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% filter from_yaml %}\n[{% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}\n{{ dict(k|zip(v)) }},\n{% endfor %}]\n{% endfilter %}\n): sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found"}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ud": [
        {
            "k1a": "v1a",
            "k1b": "v1b",
            "k1c": "v1c"
        },
        {
            "k2a": "v2a",
            "k2b": "v2b"
        },
        {
            "k3a": "v3a"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ud|type_debug": "list"
}

TASK [Test 3] ******************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% filter from_yaml %}\n{% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}\n- {{ dict(k|zip(v)) }}\n{% endfor %}\n{% endfilter %}\n): sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found"}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ud": [
        {
            "k1a": "v1a",
            "k1b": "v1b",
            "k1c": "v1c"
        },
        {
            "k2a": "v2a",
            "k2b": "v2b"
        },
        {
            "k3a": "v3a"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ud|type_debug": "list"
}
```

Comment: Post [mre] of the problem. Use the minimal playbook from my answer and post the complete output.

Comment: I have updated my post with the results of the playbooks. Seems like the {% filter from_yaml %} is causing the error. I removed {% filter from_yaml %} for the other tests and it managed to run properly.

Comment: How do I trim the whitespace from the list? {% set keys=k.keys()|map('trim') %} {% set vals=v.values()|map('trim') %} does not work on lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*`map('trim')`* works on items of a list. If you want to *trim* a dictionary's values and keys, you have to separate them first. For example, in a Jinja template

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        userdata: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for i in userdata %}
          {% set keys=i.keys()|map('trim') %}
          {% set vals=i.values()|map('trim') %}
          - {{ dict(keys|zip(vals)) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  userdata:
    [
        {
            "AliasName": "Alias Name",
            "Code": "Code",
            "DateofSubmission": "Date of Submission",
            "Description": "Description",
            "FirstName": "First Name",
            "path": "path"
        },
        {
            "AliasName": "",
            "Code": "#3091",
            "DateofSubmission": "14/5/2023",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": "Peter",
            "path": "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
        },
        {
            "AliasName": "",
            "Code": "#3092",
            "DateofSubmission": "2/5/2023",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": "Sam",
            "path": "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
        },
        {
            "AliasName": "",
            "Code": "#3093",
            "DateofSubmission": "10/5/2023",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": "Judy",
            "path": "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
        }
    ]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    userdata:
      - {"AliasName": "Alias Name",
         "Code": " Code ",
         "DateofSubmission": " Date of Submission ",
         "Description": "Description",
         "FirstName": " First Name ",
         "path": "path"}
      - {"AliasName": "",
         "Code": " #3091 ",
         "DateofSubmission": " 14/5/2023 ",
         "Description": "NIL",
         "FirstName": " Peter ",
         "path": "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"}
      - {"AliasName": "",
         "Code": " #3092 ",
         "DateofSubmission": " 2/5/2023 ",
         "Description": "NIL",
         "FirstName": " Sam ",
         "path": "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"}
      - {"AliasName": "",
         "Code": " #3093 ",
         "DateofSubmission": " 10/5/2023 ",
         "Description": "NIL",
         "FirstName": " Judy ",
         "path": "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"}

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        userdata: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for i in userdata %}
          {% set keys=i.keys()|map('trim') %}
          {% set vals=i.values()|map('trim') %}
          - {{ dict(keys|zip(vals)) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}

    - debug:
        var: userdata|to_nice_json
```

---

Q: "msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% filter from_yaml %}\n{% for i in userdata %}\n{% set keys=i.keys()|map('trim') %}\n{% set vals=i.values()|map('trim') %}\n- {{ dict(keys|zip(vals)) }}\n{% endfor %}\n{% endfilter %}\n): sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found".

A: I can't reproduce the problem. The minimal play below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    userdata:
      - {k1a: v1a, k1b: v1b, k1c: v1c}
      - {k2a: v2a, k2b: v2b}
      - {k3a: v3a}

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        userdata: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for i in userdata %}
          {% set keys=i.keys()|map('trim') %}
          {% set values=i.values()|map('trim') %}
          - {{ dict(keys|zip(values)) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}

    - debug:
        var: userdata|to_yaml
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  userdata|to_yaml: |-
    - {k1a: v1a, k1b: v1b, k1c: v1c}
    - {k2a: v2a, k2b: v2b}
    - {k3a: v3a}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

To isolate the problem try the play below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    ud:
      - {k1a: v1a, k1b: v1b, k1c: v1c}
      - {k2a: v2a, k2b: v2b}
      - {k3a: v3a}

    ud_keys: "{{ ud|json_query('[].keys(@)') }}"
    ud_vals: "{{ ud|json_query('[].values(@)') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ud_keys|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: ud_vals|to_yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}
          {{ k }} {{ v }}
          {% endfor %}
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}
          {{ dict(k|zip(v)) }}
          {% endfor %}

    - name: Test 1
      set_fact:
        ud: |
          [{% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}
          {{ dict(k|zip(v)) }},
          {% endfor %}]
    - debug:
        var: ud
    - debug:
        var: ud|type_debug

    - name: Test 2
      set_fact:
        ud: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          [{% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}
          {{ dict(k|zip(v)) }},
          {% endfor %}]
          {% endfilter %}
    - debug:
        var: ud
    - debug:
        var: ud|type_debug

    - name: Test 3
      set_fact:
        ud: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for k,v in ud_keys|zip(ud_vals) %}
          - {{ dict(k|zip(v)) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}
    - debug:
        var: ud
    - debug:
        var: ud|type_debug
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ud_keys|to_yaml: |-
    - [k1a, k1b, k1c]
    - [k2a, k2b]
    - [k3a]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ud_vals|to_yaml: |-
    - [v1a, v1b, v1c]
    - [v2a, v2b]
    - [v3a]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    ['k1a', 'k1b', 'k1c'] ['v1a', 'v1b', 'v1c']
    ['k2a', 'k2b'] ['v2a', 'v2b']
    ['k3a'] ['v3a']

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    {'k1a': 'v1a', 'k1b': 'v1b', 'k1c': 'v1c'}
    {'k2a': 'v2a', 'k2b': 'v2b'}
    {'k3a': 'v3a'}

TASK [Test 1] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ud:
  - k1a: v1a
    k1b: v1b
    k1c: v1c
  - k2a: v2a
    k2b: v2b
  - k3a: v3a

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ud|type_debug: list

TASK [Test 2] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ud:
  - k1a: v1a
    k1b: v1b
    k1c: v1c
  - k2a: v2a
    k2b: v2b
  - k3a: v3a

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ud|type_debug: list

TASK [Test 3] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ud:
  - k1a: v1a
    k1b: v1b
    k1c: v1c
  - k2a: v2a
    k2b: v2b
  - k3a: v3a

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ud|type_debug: list

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=13   changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```